# How do I get the CDF given a PDF with an indicator function?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, indicator-function

Given $$f(x)=\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2 )_{(-1,1)}(x),\,x\in\mathbb{R}$$
How do I get $F(x)$?

I know that the CDF of a random variable is defined as $$F(a)=\int_{- \infty}^{a} f(x)\,dx$$ In my case this becomes

$$F(a)=\int_{- \infty}^{a} \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)_{(-1,1)}(x)\,dx$$

I am a bit clueless as to how to handle the information provided by the indicator to compute the integral. The indicator says I should only care about the values of $x\in (-1,1)$ but the integral already has a very specific evaluation interval. How should I break up the integral? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that the value of the indicator function equals 0 outside the specified range; thus, $\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)1_{(-1,1)}dx = \dots$.  (This is a hint).  By breaking the integral up into two integrals, one over $(-\infty, -1]$ and the other over $(-1, a)$, you can get to the final result more easily.

Comment: It should be $F(a)$, not $F(x)$.  $x$ is just the variable of integration in the integral expression for $F(a)$, you are integrating it out, leaving you with $F(a)$.

Comment: @jbowman Wait, maybe this clears things up: in $f(x)$ and $F(x)$, is x the same variable? I have replaced the second $x$ with $a$ to avoid mixing them up. Does this matter? I mean why would the interval $x$ matter to $a$?

Anyways... Suppose I do $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)1_{(-1,1)}dx +\int_{-1}^{a} f(x)1_{(-1,1)}dx$ and assume the first integral equals zero because the almighty indicator says so (computing it gives a non-convergent result). The second one 
would be $\int_{-1}^{a} \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)\,dx=\frac{1}{16}(-a^4+6a^2-5)$, which is negative on $(-1,1)$. Not a CDF; im lost ...

Comment: How do you get $a^4$ and $a^2$?  What is the integral from $-1$ to $a$ of 3/4?

Comment: @jbwowman LOL, I don't know! Why is it the integral of $\frac{3}{4}$ and not of $\frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)$?

Comment: The integral of the sum is the sum of the integrals.  Your integral for the CDF is wrong; you can see that by integrating 3/4 over $(-1,a)$ and $-x^2$ over $(-1,a)$ and adding the two.

Comment: $f(-1)=0$, $F(a)=\frac{3 a}{4}+\frac{1}{4}a^3$

Comment: That would be correct if you were integrating from $0$ to $a$, but you're integrating from $-1$ to $a$.

Comment: @jbowman So, the indicator says anything outside $(-1,1)$ is zero. I know $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-1} f(x)1_{(-1,1)}dx$ is zero, but why? When and what are we testing in the indicator? What is outside $(-1,1)$ in the first integral? The integral's limits? But they aren't part of any function?!

Comment: @jbowman (@Carl) I see, I don't know what I was doing, the result is $\frac{1}{4}(-a^3+3a+2)$, which **is** non-negative and totally looks like a CDF!